# Unable to adjust Ruby block

Tags: ruby, dictionary, task, block, jruby

I am fairly new to Ruby, JRuby, etc...

I started to work on migration of certain bash scripts into Ruby, now I used a block from a different pipeline, but here its unnecessary to use it in this format as there is no need to iterate through array:

```
 all_cf = %w(
        customers
    ).map do |table_name|
        schema("columns.#{table_name}.hbase.families").gsub(/'/,'')
    end.uniq.map{|s| "{ NAME => '#{s}', VERSIONS => 1 }" }.join(',')
```

Is there an easier way to replace that array iteration and just replace #{table_name} with customers?

I tried this:

```
all_cf = task do
     schema("columns.customers.hbase.families").gsub(/'/,'')
   end.uniq.map...
```

But that just throws error and tried couple of more forms of this, but I think I still don't have a right understanding of the Ruby grammar, as I come from the PHP background I'm still struggling with this, anyone any idea how, and maybe an explanation why?

Cheers...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what `schema` does. Can you say which framework is that from, what exactly does `schema("columns.customers.hbase.families")` produce, and what you wish to get as a result? Also, the first version does not seem to be a task, but the second tries to define it so? And finally, "throws error" is rather useless without saying which error.

Comment: What does the `task` method do? Please post your errors. What is the desired result? If `task` doesn't return an array it makes no sense to call `.uniq.map` on it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I already solved my issue, but one more time thx for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the result that your original script produced:

```
"{ NAME => '#{schema("columns.customers.hbase.families").gsub(/'/,'')}', VERSION => 1 }"
```

I'm not sure what `task` is, so I don't know whether you should expect your code to work.  `uniq` is a method on Array which returns an Array with all duplicates removed:

```
> [1,2,3,1,2,1].uniq
# => [1,2,3]
```

Similarly you can look up what `map` and `join` do.